# URI in DELETE request's URI with MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have a version control service which should be accessible through our REST API. One of those operations allows to delete a directory in SVN. Ideally, I'd like to send a DELETE request with the URI of the target to delete, something like this: http://service:4711/directory/http%3A%2F%2Fsome%2Fdirectory

What happens isn't new and there are plenty of answers out there. Unfortunately, they do not work for me. Depending on what I try, I get a 404 or a 403 (due to the malicious colon).

Let me show you some code and what I've tried without success so far:

```
// The action in my controller
[HttpDelete]
[Route("directory/{uri}/")]
public void DeleteDirectory(string uri)
{
    var x = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri);
}
```

I am using MVC version 5.2.3.0.

I've tried:

- `[System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInput(false)]` on the action and/or the class.
- Setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in the `web.config`.
- Setting `requestPathInvalidCharacters=""` in the `web.config`.
- Setting `requestValidationMode="true"` in the `web.config`.

Right now, I see four possible solutions:

- I've done something wrong with the previous approaches.
- I have to create a custom `RequestValidator`.
- I have to double encode the URI in the request.
- Send a POST request instead of DELETE.

One may say, put it in the body of the DELETE request. But this option is highly controversial, so I'd like to ignore this one from the very beginning.

So what have I done wrong and what do you suggest to do?

Best regards,
   Carsten

Answer (score 1):

Colons in URI's in MVC are not allowed to be used until after the querystring '?' character in an URL, even when it is encoded as %3A.

Therefore, unless the SVN is http/s independent you could drop the initial http: from the parameter passed in an append it in the code.

Comment: Just to conclude this thread: I've decided to use POST requests. AFAIK this is a viable approach. This also allows me to delete multiple entities. Thanks for your reply!